# Different ID of element in different browser instance (python-selenium-chrome)

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I was locating the elements for selenium through the inspect function of my actual browser (chrome) and never had any issues. Now i had a case where the located element couldn't be found and i figured out that in my selenium chrome instance, the element has another ID then in my "normal" one and that's why i can't locate it.

This is the case with some other elements too and i can't spot the pattern.
In "Ikognito"-mode of chrome, i get the same values as in my normal browser, and the ids that my selenium browser gets are the same aswell everytime i launch the programm.

Does anybody have an explanation for this ? 
Is this common practise upon web developers and whats the way to go about this issue on future projects ?

Do i always have to run my selenium browser first and then extract the elements IDs out of there ?

Comment: It would help if you provided the example html that was changing - is it the actual [element id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) that is changing, or some sort of pseudo-id? Does the element have classes or other attributes that exhibit the same behaviour. Sounds weird though.

Comment: i assume they generate the IDs dynamically.
its the actual element id that is changing, and no the class and data-type stay the same.

Comment: If the class stays the same and it unique to the element that you're after within the context of the hierarchy that you are crawling then that might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Although locating elements by [`id`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp) is the preferred way, it is not the only one, the are [way more options](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) like:

- `name` attribute
- link text for [`a`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) elements
- partial link text for [`a`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) elements
- HTML [`tag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tag) name
- [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) attribute
- [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
- [XPath selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath)

The latter one - XPath is the most powerful as it's almost a programming language. Unlike other selector strategies XPath selectors have full awareness of DOM page, can lookup all attributes, text, parent/child objects, traverse [axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes) and if it's not enough you can go for [functions and operators](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) to precisely select whatever element is needed.

With regards to dynamic IDs - it's quite a common practice when the page is not deterministic and the content is dynamic. Theoretically you can ask your application developers to come up with a custom [HTML attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) which will be used for automation and maybe [user tracking](https://help.opentracker.net/article/93-how-does-user-tracking-work), but if for some reason it is not possible - you will have to define another way of locating the element.s

Comment: i already use xpath as a selection method

but i use ...//span[@id='1' and ... ] as a subselector, because it the core element can only be determined through id and the displayed text. 

I know have a build around, i was just curious if this is a reoccuring theme that ids often change and i was wondering on which circumstances this might occur.